# Magento2: How do inject dependencies into CLI commands

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to figure out how to use or inject dependencies properly in Magento 2 CLI commands. From https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html:

> Your command can use the Object Manager and Magento dependency injection features; for example, it can use constructor dependency injection.

Object Manager (`Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager`) is simple enough, even though other parts of the doc discourage use of it for some reason. How does "constructor dependency injection" work with CLI commands? `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command`'s constructor just takes in a string, so that doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the constructor dependencies were cached in the `generated` (M2.4.1) directory, which had to be manually removed for the DI to work properly. Other than that, following https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use dependency injection into the constructor of CLI commands.

You can check on some Magento native CLIs.
Example `php bin/magento store:list`, you can check on `Magento\Store\Console\Command\StoreListCommand`. They injected storeManager into the constructor to use it like normally

Comment: Reason I couldn't get DI to work was because the DI parameters were cached in `generated` directory. Without manually removing this directory, the changes I made to the constructor would not take effect.